# Do we need chunk in iText7.0 pdf? As i am converting screens from itext2.0 to 7.0 what should i do with chunk?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

```
Chunk newAssessmentMarker = new Chunk(" ");
    newAssessmentMarker.setGenericTag("NewAssessment");
    Paragraph newAssessmentParagraph = new Paragraph();
    newAssessmentParagraph.add(newAssessmentMarker);
```

As shown above i am using chunk to store some spaces. Can i use Paragraph to perform same operation?

Comment: What exactly do you set the generic tag for? Knowing that might be crucial for determining how exactly to port that `Chunk` use.

Answer (score 0):

A `Text` object would be the best fit for this use of `Chunk`.

For some more information on this topic, have a look at the [building blocks tutorial](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/we-start-overview-classes-and-interfaces)